# SSRS calculation expression for specific value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I'm looking at doing a calculation expression in SSRS but I've become unstuck.

I'm trying to calculate when a field equals a specific value, then return a percentage calculation.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Alert.Value="Red",(FormatPercent(Count(Fields!Sales.Value) / 6532 ,0)))SUM(IIF(Fields!Alert.Value="Yellow",(FormatPercent(Count(Fields!Sales.Value) / 2541 ,0)))SUM(IIF(Fields!Alert.Value="Green",(FormatPercent(Count(Fields!Sales.Value) / 1025,0)))
```

Obviously this is incorrect and doesn't work. The expression needs to include all 3 colours.

Comment: You don't have `False` parts to the `IIF` statements.  Are you summing up the `%` values? And your opening and closing parenthesis don't match up.

Comment: in its basic form, when something is 'red' I want it to look at total sales field and divide that number by 6532 * 100 to give a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED** see if this works.

**UPDATED per requested.** I put the statement in the last `False` part, but I'm not sure if this is what you really want.

**UPDATED again.** Added `False` part to the last `IIF` statement.

**UPDATED:** Removed the `SUM` function. Try this to see if it works. Your `IIF` statement didn't have any `False` parts. Also, just `SUM` once around the whole statement if you want it summed. Not knowing your data, I'm not sure if you want the `%` summed up.

```
=IIF(Fields!location.Value="East" AND Fields!Alert.Value="Red",(FormatPercent(Count(Fields!Sales.Value) / 6532 ,0)),IIF(Fields!Alert.Value="Yellow",FormatPercent(Count(Fields!Sales.Value) / 2541 ,0),IIF(Fields!Alert.Value="Green",FormatPercent(Count(Fields!Sales.Value) / 1025,0),0)))
```

Comment: this is what I get now      'Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object'.'       appreciate your efforts

Comment: This is great, however I forgot that required this in the expression as well, how can insert this correctly please?    =Count(IIF(Fields!location.Value="East",(Fields!sales.Value) ,Nothing))

Comment: I updated the answer, but I'm not sure if this is what you want. Did you want to get a `%` as well, like the other results?

Comment: so when in the 'East' and  is 'red' I want it to look at total sales field and divide that number by 6532 * 100 to give a percentage             this is the error I get now   The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox2.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30205] End of statement expected.

Comment: ok, there was one extra bracket which wasn't required, have deleted that and the expression runs.  Judging by the numbers i'm getting, i'm thinking its not filtering out the 'East' part correctly

Comment: So, you want to check `East` and `Red`, otherwise the other `IIF` statements? Let me update.